# Dose mongodb has RDBMS capabilities?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, rdbms

Is it possible to use `Monogodb` like `mysql`, `Sql` etc.? 
Dose it support index `primary key`, `foreign key` in `collations`?

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent documentation on the comparison between Mongodb and MySQL
Take a look [here](https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql?jmp=docs)

Primary key in MongoDB is basically the `_id` field. You can set any value you want. If you don't initialize it, then it is automatically generated for you with an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

Regarding your question on primary and foreign key there are also excellent documentations.

- [One-to-One Relationships](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/)
- [One-to-Many with Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)
- [One-to-Many with Document references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)